# multiple columns from single column in python

Tags: pandas

I am trying to split a column into multiple columns

The column has values like this:

```
 message
 ------------
 time=15:45:19 devname="FG3H0E3917903319" devid="FG3H0E3917903319" 
 logid="1059028705" type="utm" subtype="app-ctrl" eventtype="app-ctrl-all" 
level="warning" vd="root" eventtime=1564226119 appid=16009 
srcip=172.24.208.2 dstip=93.184.221.240 srcport=4832 dstport=80 
srcintf="LAN-RahaNet" srcintfrole="lan" dstintf="WAN-RahaNet" 
dstintfrole="lan" proto=6 service="HTTP" direction="outgoing" policyid=43 
 sessionid=493024483 applist="LanAppControl" appcat="Update" 
app="MS.Windows.Update" action="block" 
hostname="www.download.windowsupdate.com" incidentserialno=1522726002 
url="/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootseq.txt" msg="Update: 
MS.Windows.Update," apprisk="elevated"
```

Basically I need to split this column into:

```
time         devname                devid           ...
--------------------------------------------------------------
15:45:19    FG3H0E3917903319     FG3H0E3917903319     ...
```

Comment: Is this column a dictionary?

Comment: Does your dataframe contain more columns, or is it only one column. What you present looks very similar to a json dolument, except, that the `=` would have to be translated to `:` the keys would have to be separated by `,` and the documents contained in `{}`.  The documents then again need to be separated by commas and placed between `[]`.

Comment: If you just have this column in the dataframe, you have the source of the dataframe as a text file and are working on a unix-like system, I'd suggest you to try to preprocess it using `sed` to make the file a proper JSON file and then load it with `pd.read_json`.

Comment: my dataframe have other column/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer:

1. split the message on space, to get a list of key value pairs.
2. split every key-value pair on `=` sign.
3. add corresponding keys to their respective columns.